# Use Authorization Roles and Policies in Blazor WebAssembly with Identity?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am using a Blazor WebAssembly `3.2-preview3` application scaffolded with Identity that has created the following 3 projects:

```
App.Client
App.Server
App.Shared
```

My `IdentityUser` implementation is called `AppUser`, and my `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` implementation is called `AppDb`

I have a role called `Admin` that has been assigned to administrators, and a Policy called `RequireAdmin` that checks for the `Admin` role.  However, when I try to use an `AuthorizeView` in `App.Client` and view the page with an administrator, it does not show the link.

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="RequireAdmin">
    <Authorized>
        <a class="nav-link" href="admin">Admin</a>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

How can I enable roles and policies in my Blazor WebAssembly application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Create Roles and Policies in App.Shared**

Add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/) package to the `App.Shared` project

Add the following 2 classes in the `App.Shared` project to define Roles and Policies that will be used by the Client and Server.

*Shared/RoleTypes.cs*

```
namespace App.Shared
{
    public static class RoleTypes
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
    }
}
```

*Shared/PolicyTypes.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace App.Shared
{
    public static class PolicyTypes
    {
        public const string RequireAdmin = "RequireAdmin";

        public static AuthorizationOptions AddAppPolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options)
        {
            options.AddPolicy(RequireAdmin, policy =>
                policy.RequireRole(RoleTypes.Admin));
            return options;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Configure services in App.Server**

Modify the `Startup.cs` file in the `App.Server` project to add your policies by calling the extension method that was just defined in `App.Shared`.

Also modify it to include the `role` claim in the `openid` scope.

*Server/Startup.cs*

```
using App.Shared;
...

namespace App.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {

        ...

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDb>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<AppUser, AppDb>(options =>
                {
                    // https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649
                    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
                });
            // Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddAppPolicies());

            ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Configure services in App.Client**

Modify the `Program.cs` file in the `App.Client` project to add your policies by calling the extension method that was just defined in `App.Shared`.  Also modify `AddApiAuthorization` to configure the `role` claim.

*Client/Program.cs*

```
using App.Client.Services;
using App.Shared;
...

namespace App.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...

            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.AddAppPolicies());
            // 2 calls to AddApiAuthorization are necessary in 3.2-preview3
            // should be fixed in 3.2-preview4
            // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19854
            // https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649#issuecomment-612442543
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
            });

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  The only problem I now have is if the user has multiple roles.  If you inspect the JWT token the roles are returned as an array:  "role": [
    "Clinician",
    "Patient"
  ]     and this does not work client side